# Há algum problema em usar objetos dessa forma no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou trabalhando em um sistema que contém um CRUD simples para tabelas de um banco Postgres, em que tabelas novas podem ser acrescentadas eventualmente. Então, para evitar reescrever os *controllers* o tempo todo, eu fiz o seguinte:

```
const repositorio1 = require('caminho/do/repositorio1');
const repositorio2 = require('caminho/do/repositorio2');
const repositorio3 = require('caminho/do/repositorio3');

const repos = {
'rep1' : repositorio1,
'rep2' : repositorio2,
'rep3' : repositorio3
}

//exemplo de um get
exports.get = async(req, res, next) => {
  let rep = (req.url).split('/')[1];
  try{
    var data = await repos[rep].get();
    res.status(200).send(data);
  }catch(e){
    res.status(500).send("erro");
  }
};
```

Dessa forma fica apenas um *controller* para todos os repositórios.

Eu perco desempenho com o código escrito dessa forma?

Tem alguma diferença de eu escrever ele assim?

```
const repos = {
'rep1' : require('caminho/do/repositorio1'),
'rep2' : require('caminho/do/repositorio2'),
'rep3' : require('caminho/do/repositorio3')
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declarar constantes antes ou ter o require diretamente dentro do objeto é irrelevante em termos de performance. É boa prática ter os requires declarados no inicio do ficheiro, por isso podes escolher essa versão que é como tens.

Teres só um controlador é excelente. É [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120931/o-dry-%C3%A9-para-evitar-redund%C3%A2ncias-certo) e por isso fácil de manter e é também uma só função a ter em memória. Esse tipo de funcionalidade numa aplicação é bom não ter espalhado por diversos sítios ou funções, mesmo que não seja código repetido.